# How can I use the same build to make a 10-inch tablet version of my app?

Tags: android-layout, android

I developed an Android application and published it in the Market. Now I want to make that same application for 10-inch tablets. The problem is when I run my build for 10-inch tablets, it works well but raises some UI issues involving display texts and layout heights. Textual titles look good in the handset version but very small in the tablet version.

How can I programmatically find out if the APK is running on handset, a 10-inch tablet, or a 7-inch tablet? And how can I maintain text sizes and view sizes based on screen sizes? I don't want to make separate XML files for each resolution like (large, xlarge).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way to do this if it's just a matter of changing a few text sizes and dimensions is to use a single layout in which you reference dimension or style resources.  For example, your layout can have one `TextView` with its text size declared as:

```
android:textSize="@dimen/descriptive_text_size_label"
```

another view can have its height declared with:

```
android:layout_height="@dimen/descriptive_layout_height_label"
```

and yet another view could have several properties grouped together in a style:

```
style="@style/descriptive_style_label"
```

Then, in the `res/values-MODIFIER` directory, you have, e.g. `styles.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="descriptive_style_label">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">6dp</item>
  </style>

  <dimen name="descriptive_layout_height_label">120dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="descriptive_text_size_label">16dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

So you'd have tablet values in `res/values-xlarge` and default values in `res/values`.

If you need to make more drastic changes in your layout, you can use a separate layout, but reuse components with `<include>`.

Comment: Hi, your i agree with you. i tried this by creating res/values-xlarge/string.xml file for large screen and used test_size is 25dp but it doesn't effect. Can you please gave me code what is worked code for you.

Comment: May be <dimen name="descriptive_text_size_label">16dp</dimen> is not getting in android:textSize="@dimen/descriptive_text_size_label"

Comment: @RaghuRamiReddy The code I posted is working code; all I changed are the names. Please post your code that isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

As you mention you don't want to create new xml files so, I think you should check the device programmatically i.e you can check for device width using i think WindowManager.. then set your font and layout params according to it.
But i suggest you to do using xml approach it makes your work easy.

hope this helps you if need more help fell free to ask..